# URLConnection Character Encoding

Tags: java, encoding, httpurlconnection

I am trying to read a JSON string:

```
{
  "also_known_as": [
    "Сильвестр Сталлоне"
  ],

  "birthday": "1946-07-06",
  "deathday": "",
}
```

over HTTP.

I have the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("url");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");//connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
    writer.write(line);
}
reader.close();
writer.close();     
connection.disconnect();
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

But it is printing the string in console:

```
{
  "also_known_as": [
    "Ð¡Ð¸Ð»ÑŒÐ²ÐµÑ?Ñ‚Ñ€ Ð¡Ñ‚Ð°Ð»Ð»Ð¾Ð½Ðµ"
  ],

  "birthday": "1946-07-06",
  "deathday": "",
}
```

I have also tried:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));//BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
```

But no luck.

My question is how can I set the character encoding of the URLConnection?

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Regards.

---

Using Apache IOUtils I have tried this:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(connection.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
```

But it is printing same result in the console of eclipse.

---

Using Apache HttpClient:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/person/16483?api_key=23e89da030a0ee8b25aaed20950a0c25");
getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(response.getEntity().getContent(), writer, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```

same result.

Comment: you have to encode BufferedReader or StringWriter with proper Charset

Comment: @mKorbel I have tried to use IOUtils. I have edited my answer. But it is giving same result too. :(

Comment: Are you sure it's not that your console's charset is set improperly?

Comment: there is common issue that Windows OS pretty complicated simple things, you have to search for Charset or Windows EncodePage for [Cyrilic types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_script) `String my String = new String(reader.toByteArray(), charEncoding);`

Comment: @SeanOwen, The Encoding of the console of eclipse was set to Default - inherited (Cp1252), I changed it to UTF-8, now it is printing properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just popping out my comment into an answer, which turned out to be the cause: the console's character set was Cp1252, so the output was correct but being displayed incorrectly.

Comment: Today the EU fined Microsoft 500 Million EUR for not offering a different browser. This is unjust, IMHO. What would be just: Fine them 500 Million EUR *every day* this damned and absolutely useless, non-standard CP1252 is just set as standard encoding, and there is no way to change that!

Answer (score 1):

Make that:

```
new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), new Charset("UTF-8"))
```

i.e. specify that charset.

Comment: That’s wrong.  You have to examine the HTTP header for the charset. You cannot assume UTF-8.

Comment: @tchrist Well, yeah. In that case `connection.getContentType()` and parse.

Comment: @Manish unfortunately, many websites do not care to specify the charset properly. What would be the standard in such cases?

Comment: @Ingo - According to [the HTTP 1.1 spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.7.1) the default charset for "text" MIME content types received via HTTP is ISO-8859-1.